# What is the meaning of the word "inriation"?

Tags: meaning, dictionaries

I looked up the definition of the word elation in Webster's Revised Unabridged 1913 dictionary and found the following definition  (Page: 476):

> Elation
>
> E*la"tion (?), n. [L. elatio. See Elate.] A lifting up by success; exaltation; inriation with pride of prosperity. Felt the elation of triumph." Sir W. Scott."

I had never seen the word inriation before and my subsequent attempts to find a definition failed. It is not listed as a word in the 1913 dictionary, or any others that I've found.

Is there an example of this word in English literature? Is it made-up, a misspelling? I can infer the definition from context, but is there any dictionary where inriation is defined?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

*inflation with pride of prosperity*

It is most likely an OCR error concerning an exotic fl ligature being interpreted as ri -> **inflation**.

This maybe due to poor inking of the top left quadrant of the ligature in the original, or poor thesholding during the OCR. In either case this would lose the upper branch of the f, but the dot being the f terminal serif would remain.

Reasoning:

- pride is something which is often said to be pumped up or otherwise swolen or aerated.
- I studied the OCR errors of noisy, hot-Lead typeset documents as part of my Computer Science doctorate.

Comment: I think you're right. The error has been [perpetuated](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=A+lifting+up+by+success%3B+exaltation%3B+inriation+with+pride+of+prosperity.) though; and at least [one scholarly work](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?action=search&word=elation&resource=Webster%27s&quicksearch=on) also reproduces it.

Comment: Wow, it's scary that how all these dictionary are inter-linked. I can't find a definition that uses the correct word "inflation"

Comment: So... due to a typographical error, *inriation* has become a word? Now all we gotta do is invent what it means, exactly, so that those dictionary definitions of *elation* make sense, but so that it's not redundant synonym for *inflation*...

Comment: Google Books gives some good examples: e.g. ["inflation"](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3j4ka.png), but also with ["variation"](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hly1Q.png) (and [another "variation"](http://i.stack.imgur.com/AugTE.png)). But you can see the ["inflation of mind" definition](https://archive.org/stream/websterspractica00web#page/123/mode/1up) in an earlier Webster's edition.

Comment: If it was OCR, I'd wonder if the Gutenberg [translation to ebook](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/29765) should have fixed this. It certainly would be nice to see the source book.  On the other hand, [this](http://books.google.com/books?id=RA0UAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA6&lpg=PA6&dq=inriation&source=bl&ots=wd6L4h3Gk5&sig=gTFLrzNyXbanrXbjx_Q387W5m0w&hl=en&sa=X&ei=JQUPVLvIA43KgwSNsYGQDA&ved=0CEQQ6AEwBjgK#v=onepage&q=inriation&f=false) is certainly an OCR problem. [other examples](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=inriation&gws_rd=ssl)

Comment: @hyde Many words have been created due to hearing or pronunciation errors. Why not for typographical reasons? We have a whole dialect of text-speak due to the needs of instant message.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah, absolutely. I just hope the creator of the original mistake does not become too inriated with fame and start doing it on purpose with other words.